# VSTO Outlook: Getting Outlook mail item size on receiving a new email

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-interop, office-addins

When I receive a new Outlook email, in the NewMailEx event handler, I try to get the total size of the email (including attachments) by doing below:

```
omi = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetItemFromID(entryId) as Outlook.MailItem;
int emailSize = omi.Size;
```

I have debug an put a breakpoint just when getting the size and I get an error saying:

> error CS1061: 'MailItem' does not contain a definition for 'Size' and
> no accessible extension method 'Size' accepting a first argument of
> type 'MailItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
> an assembly reference?)

Any ideas what is happening this?

Comment: It would be great to specify the Outlook version where you got this exception and the PIAs used in the project.

Comment: If you go to the MailItem object definition (hit F12), what other properties do you see?

Answer (score 1):

Try to handle the `ItemAdd` event on the `Inbox` folder and get the property value.

Typically you may get such exception if old PIAs are used or your Outlook is quite old and doesn't support the property used in the code.

The last resort is to try using the late-binding technology instead, see [Type.InvokeMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.invokemember?view=net-7.0) for more information.